# Running explorer as 32 bit on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

How can you run a 32 bit version of explorer on 64 bit windows 7 x64?

This is to allow tortoisehg to work.

I've tried running "c:\windows\syswow64\explorer /separate" and it just starts another version of the 64 bit explorer.

Comment: Hm, confirmed on Stack Overflow (see last answers): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746/hgtortoise-in-vista-64-bit-not-showing-the-context-menu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no 32bit explored executable bundled with 64bit win7, so you cant.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, except possibly the last two words. 32-bit explorer is found in typical installations at C:\Windows\SysWow64\explorer.exe

Comment: see also:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/e237260d-ca42-4fbc-a657-89796d884715

Comment: While the 32-bit version exists, as user26523 points out, you still can't run it. I assume it's there for library (et al) calls only. The fact that it will not run also suggest it might not actually be a full copy of explorer in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there's currently no known way of getting this to work in Windows 7 (does in Vista though) according to the answers further down here: [Stackoverflow question 39746](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746/hgtortoise-in-vista-64-bit-not-showing-the-context-menu)

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Virtual XP Mode" addon.  I am running Windows 7 64-bit and use the Cisco VPN and XP 32-bit IE for connecting to the corporate network.

Comment: The ShrewSoft (or other) VPN Client is a much more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to run 32-bit Explorer if you stop all other instances of the Explorer.exe process.  Including your desktop shell.  (Note that sometimes it can hang around in the background.)

Comment: Nope. That doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There's a 64-bit version of TortoiseHg right on their download page:

http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/download/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is:

If you start a app or script from a Desktop shortcut or Windows Explorer (= 64-bit applications on 64-bit Windows!) the script runs in 64-bit mode. But if you start the same script from a 32-bit application such as **Total Commander** the scripts runs in 32-bit mode.

Copied from http://www.iopus.com/iMacros/support/x64.htm

Answer (score 0):

Explorer++ is the solution that worked for us to run ClearCase. All our context menu's display in explorer++ and is also useful as it has Tabs in it